# Events don't show on first, main view of calendar

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, calendarkit

I am using `SwiftUI`, `UIKit` and external library [CalendarKit](https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit) in my project. The problem is that events don't load (while initializing ) on first view ( first load ) of calendar ( the current day view ). When I change date in the `NavBar`, update event or create new event everything works fine. Events are reloading and are showed up on screen.

I have few classes in my projects. First is `CalendarScreen` which renders the `SwiftUI` view, ViewModel of `CalendarScreen` which loads data fetched from API. Service which provides repository and Repository class which runs URLRequest. The `UIKit` class of `DayViewController` where everything is going in:

```
class CalendarViewController: DayViewController {
  convenience init(viewModel: CalendarScreen.ViewModel) {
    self.init()
    self.viewModel = viewModel
  }
  var viewModel = CalendarScreen.ViewModel()
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    reloadData()
  }
  override func reloadData() {
    dayView.timelinePagerView.pagingViewController.children.forEach({ (controller) in
      if let controller = controller as? TimelineContainerController {
        controller.timeline.layoutAttributes = eventsForDate(Date()).map(EventLayoutAttributes.init)
      }
    })
  }
  override func eventsForDate(_ date: Date) -> [EventDescriptor] {
    return viewModel.fetchCalendarEvents { _ in
      var calendarKitEvents = [Event()]
      calendarKitEvents = self.viewModel.calendarEvents.compactMap { item in
        let event = Event()
        event.dateInterval = DateInterval(
          start: self.dateTimeFormat.date(from: item.start) ?? Date(),
          end: self.dateTimeFormat.date(from: item.end) ?? Date())
        event.color = UIColor(InvoiceColor(title: item.title))
        event.isAllDay = false
        event.text = item.title
        return event
      }
      self.eventsOnCeldanr = calendarKitEvents
      return self.eventsOnCeldanr
    }
  }
}
```

And the classes corresponding to my `APICall` the main function is `func fetchCalendarEvents` which return `Events` to my `Controller`

```
class Agent {
  let session = URLSession.shared
  func run<T: Decodable>(_ request: URLRequest) -> AnyPublisher<T, Error> {
    return
      session
      .dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
      .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
      .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}

struct CalendarRepository {
  private let agent = Agent()
  func getEvents() -> AnyPublisher<[CalendarEvent], Error> {
    let urlString = "\(calendarurl)"
    let url = URL(string: urlString)!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    return agent.run(request)
  }
}

struct CalendarService {
  private var calendarRepository = CalendarRepository()
  func getEvents() -> AnyPublisher<[CalendarEvent], Error> {
    return calendarRepository.getEvents()
  }

  extension CalendarScreen {
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
      let calendarService = CalendarService()
      @Published var calendarEvents: [CalendarEvent]
      @Published var events: [Event]
      var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
      init() {
        self.calendarEvents = [CalendarEvent()]
        self.events = []
      }
      func fetchCalendarEvents(_ completion: @escaping ([EventDescriptor]) -> [EventDescriptor])
        -> [EventDescriptor]
      {
        cancellable = calendarService.getEvents()
          .sink(
            receiveCompletion: { _ in },
            receiveValue: {
              calendarEvents in self.calendarEvents = calendarEvents
              NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .onEventLoaded, object: nil)
              self.createEvents()
              completion(self.events)
            })
        return events
      }
      func createEvents() {
        self.events = self.calendarEvents.compactMap({ (item) in
          var event = Event()
          event.dateInterval = DateInterval(
            start: self.dateTimeFormat.date(from: item.start)!,
            end: self.dateTimeFormat.date(from: item.end)!)
          event.color = UIColor(InvoiceColor(title: item.title))
          event.isAllDay = false
          event.text = item.title
          return event
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So the problem is when I load view for the first time the `reloadDate()` returning empty `[]` array.While i try to debug `events` are in variable `calendarKitEvents` but without sucessful `return` t Events don't show up on my calendar.[image]

But when I switch dates lets say for next date and switch back to current day events show up [image]

I am thinking that I don't know how to proper load Events on init view of Calendar. I tried to use `reloadData()` in every possible moment but without success. Moreover I tried to `reloadData()` in `updateUIViewController`. Events show up but it gives me a infinite loop of request to fetch data.

Comment: Thanks for only including relevant classes, but this is a lot to read. Try to create a minimal example, or at least remove irrelevant code, such as import statements, print statements, and view modifiers. Much more likely to get an answer :)

Comment: I modified my question to your recommendations @Stoic

Comment: @XoliKnightPlease please add implementation of reload data

Comment: @teja_D `reloadData` functionallity coming from `CalendarKit` event which is avaliable on GitHub but i added it aswell. I Also added `updateTimeline` function to my post wich also comes from the library

Comment: @XoliKnight Could please check if  self.updateTimeline(controller.timeline) statement is getting executed or not using breakpoints or log

Comment: @teja_D yes, whem i am loading the screen for first time `updateTimeline` statement is getting executed. I used the `breakpoints` because i dont know how use `log`

Comment: @XoliKnight Where is your API call to get the data from server?

Comment: @teja_D i added API call to my question you can check it out but it is simple request with `completion` return

Comment: @XoliKnight How does your API request is getting called on viewDidLoad()?

Comment: @teja_D the `override func eventsForDate` function is used when `reloadData()` is called at least from what I can infer

Comment: @XoliKnight So have you checked if that overridden method is getting called after viewDidLoad()?

Comment: @teja_D its called but after that `eventsForDate` it is not called as usual. You found a problem any tips to solve it?

Comment: @teja_D so i rewrite `reloadData` function and in first call variable `events` is empty